# Email belongs to User - Using Email as username Cakephp 2.0.5

Tags: database-design, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a table email_addresses and a table users.  I am using the users email address as their username.  So the users table would be something like:

```
email_address_id
password
```

The email_address_id field would just find the email in the email_addresses table for the username as login information.

I understand I can change the username field to another name like email_address with the auth component, but how would I use a field from a different table as a username?

Right now I have to insert the email in the email table AND the user table which seems like really bad database design.

Any help would be appreciated!

I'm using CakePHP 2.0.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need to do this? It's good to keep things that belongs together, together.

I would keep the email in the User model for authentication.

Use email_addresses for subsequent emails if that's what you want.

**Edit:**

Now if some people are granted access and other not, I would add a field in the User model, something like has_access int(1) or whatever speaks to you and check it's value at login.

Comment: I agree.. there is also something fishy about your relationship. Looking at [this diagram](http://mboffin.com/stuff/ruby-on-rails-data-relationships.png), the table with the foreign key *belongs to* the other table. So where you say "Email belongs to User", you really mean "User belongs to Email". This inherently means that either "Email hasMany Users" or "Email hasOne User". Do you really plan on associating one email address to many user accounts? Also, if this is a hasOne (1:1 relationship) instead, then why the extra table?

Comment: Well I have email addresses for people other than those who will log in to the database.  For example it works like this: Person hasOne EmailAddress - EmailAddress belongsTo Person. Then some of these "people" will also be allowed to log in.  Their email address which already exists in the table email_addresses will become their username.  So I would have to insert their email_address to a new table.  It's not a hasMany relationship only one email per user, I just don't see the point in adding data that already exists in the database somewhere else.

Comment: Actually I was wrong about the tables I'm currently using, although I don't think it changes anything.  I have the email address as a field in the people table.  So only one address per person and then I was thinking potentially the person would log in with the email field from the persons table as their username.  If I wasn't using Cake, I feel like this is the best way to design the database.  I can't have the emails ONLY in the users table because not all people will be users.  Why duplicate data?  I don't see the benefit.